# Data is being overwritten in three different adapters

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**I am trying to put three different data in three recyclerView with same adapter and only one modelClass becuse the datas put in them are of same type but the data is being overWritten and the last data is shown only. I am using picasso library to download and show the images**
**Here is my mainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyclvw);
    recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyclvw2);
    recyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcyclvw3);

    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this,movieList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager nLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager oLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    nAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this,batDetails);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(nLayoutManager);
    recyclerView2.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(nAdapter);

    oAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this,theWoman);
    recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(oLayoutManager);
    recyclerView3.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView3.setAdapter(oAdapter);

    prepareMovieData();
}

private void prepareMovieData() {
    ModelClass model = new ModelClass();
    model.setImg("http://www.twothirdsoftheplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/iron-man-e1447971107543.png");
    model.setGenre("I love Ironman");
    model.setTitle("Ironman 1");
    movieList.add(model);


    ModelClass model2 = new ModelClass();
    model2.setImg("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/f/fb/Marvel-avengers-infinity-war-iron-man-sixth-scale-figure-hot-toys-silo-903421.png/revision/latest?cb=20180318221316");
    model2.setGenre("Shuri is better than Ironman only in technology.");
    model2.setTitle("Ironman 2");
    movieList.add(model2);

    ModelClass model3 = new ModelClass();
    model3.setImg("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4e/8c/ca/4e8cca10fd6b2bd509090078cdb0a19c.png");
    model3.setGenre("Everyone loves Ironman.");
    model3.setTitle("Ironman 3");
    movieList.add(model3);

    ModelClass model4 = new ModelClass();
    model4.setImg("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91qvAndeVYL._RI_.jpg");
    model4.setGenre("Who the hell hates Ironman.");
    model4.setTitle("Ironman 4");
    movieList.add(model4);

    ModelClass model5 = new ModelClass();
    model5.setImg("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oRuNf5hpL._SY355_.jpg");
    model5.setGenre("Avengers: The End Game,is going to be an awesome movie.");
    model5.setTitle("Ironman 5");
    movieList.add(model5);

    ModelClass model1 = new ModelClass();
    model1.setImg("https://www.sideshowtoy.com/assets/products/903341-iron-man-mark-iv/lg/marvel-iron-man-2-iron-man-mark-4-sixth-scale-figure-hot-toys-903340-08.jpg");
    model1.setGenre("Ironman is awesome.");
    model1.setTitle("Ironman 6");
    movieList.add(model1);

    ModelClass bat1 = new ModelClass();
    bat1.setImg("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/03/11/51/batman-312342_960_720.png");
    bat1.setTitle("Batman 1");
    bat1.setGenre("It Is Black");
    batDetails.add(bat1);

    ModelClass bat2 = new ModelClass();
    bat2.setImg("https://media1.popsugar-assets.com/files/thumbor/0HCrBI6oAjeS76tdNN_79aOCUN4/fit-in/1024x1024/filters:format_auto-!!-:strip_icc-!!-/2012/07/29/2/192/1922153/eccf49d595e40bcb_Anne-Hathaway/i/Anne-Hathaway.jpg");
    bat2.setTitle("Batman 2");
    bat2.setGenre("It Is Black");
    batDetails.add(bat2);

    ModelClass bat3 = new ModelClass();
    bat3.setImg("https://www.sideshowtoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/dc-comics-batman-premium-format-figure-sideshow-feature-300542-1.jpg");
    bat3.setTitle("Batman 3");
    bat3.setGenre("It Is Black");
    batDetails.add(bat3);

    ModelClass bat4 = new ModelClass();
    bat4.setImg("https://www.sideshowtoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/dc-comics-justice-league-batman-statue-prime1-studio-feature-903246-1.jpg");
    bat4.setTitle("Batman 4");
    bat4.setGenre("It Is Black");
    batDetails.add(bat4);

    ModelClass woman = new ModelClass();
    woman.setGenre("Lorem Ipsum");
    woman.setTitle("Wondr Woman 1");
    woman.setImg("https://www.dccomics.com/sites/default/files/Movies-Gallery_JusticeLeague2017_WW_59f8be1fcea248.19685240.jpg");
    theWoman.add(woman);

    ModelClass woman2 = new ModelClass();
    woman2.setGenre("Lorem Ipsum");
    woman2.setTitle("Wondr Woman 1");
    woman2.setImg("https://assets.change.org/photos/7/wk/bh/pUWkBhduwOtRAVV-800x450-noPad.jpg?1509858171");
    theWoman.add(woman2);

    ModelClass woman3 = new ModelClass();
    woman3.setGenre("Lorem Ipsum");
    woman3.setTitle("Wondr Woman 1");
    woman3.setImg("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91I2JspDFLL._RI_.jpg");
    theWoman.add(woman3);

    ModelClass woman4 = new ModelClass();
    woman4.setGenre("Lorem Ipsum");
    woman4.setTitle("Wondr Woman 1");
    woman4.setImg("https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/wonder-woman-pictures-3840x2160.jpg");
    theWoman.add(woman4);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    nAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<ModelClass> listtr;
    public MoviesAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ModelClass> listtr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listtr=listtr;

    }

    @Override
    public MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_row_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelClass movie = movieList.get(position);
       ModelClass bat =batDetails.get(position);
        ModelClass womn=theWoman.get(position);
        holder.titl.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.titl.setText(bat.getTitle());
        holder.titl.setText(womn.getTitle());
        holder.genr.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.genr.setText(bat.getGenre());
        holder.genr.setText(womn.getGenre());
        //holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
        // holder.imgvw.setImageResource(Picasso.with(context).load(moviesList.get(position).getImg()));
        Picasso.with(context).load(movie.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);
       Picasso.with(context).load(bat.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);
        Picasso.with(context).load(womn.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listtr.size();


    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgvw;
        private TextView titl, genr;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            titl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
            genr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            imgvw = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        }
    }
```

**here is my modelClass.java**

```
public class ModelClass {
private String img, Title, genre;

public ModelClass() {

}

public ModelClass(String img, String title, String genre) {

    this.img = img;
    Title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
}

}
```

**Here is my movie_row_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgview"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/settext" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgview"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/heading"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgview"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Thanks in Adavance..**

Answer (score 0):

No need to set value for each recylerviews. Make it common.

**Change**

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelClass movie = movieList.get(position);
   ModelClass bat =batDetails.get(position);
    ModelClass womn=theWoman.get(position);
    holder.titl.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.titl.setText(bat.getTitle());
    holder.titl.setText(womn.getTitle());
    holder.genr.setText(movie.getGenre());
    holder.genr.setText(bat.getGenre());
    holder.genr.setText(womn.getGenre());
    //holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
    // holder.imgvw.setImageResource(Picasso.with(context).load(moviesList.get(position).getImg()));
    Picasso.with(context).load(movie.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);
   Picasso.with(context).load(bat.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);
    Picasso.with(context).load(womn.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);
}
```

**To**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelClass model = listtr.get(position);

    holder.titl.setText(model.getTitle());     
    holder.genr.setText(model.getGenre());
    //holder.year.setText(model.getYear());
    // holder.imgvw.setImageResource(Picasso.with(context).load(moviesList.get(position).getImg()));
    Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImg()).into(holder.imgvw);   

}
```

Hope it helps.!

Comment: Welcome glad to help.